# VS Code Extension: Order of extension's settings/configurations?

Tags: settings, vscode-extensions

this question is related to development of a VSCode Extension. My extension has configuration keys / settings that will be exposed to the user. The user will be able to set these configuration options as User Settings or as Workspace Settings.
Since VSCode 1.66 there is a new property "order" for  Extensions with many configuration keys / settings. This property "order" allows to sort these configuration keys / settings. I have installed VSCode 1.75.1 but the order of the configuration keys / settings is still in alphabetical order

This is an extract of the package.json file. Each configuration key / setting has a "order" property.

```
 {
  "title": "Linebreaks SELECT",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "sqlinform.ID148LinebreakAfterSelect": {
      "order": 10,
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "Linebreak After SELECT"
      
    },
    "sqlinform.ID185LinebreakBeforeInto": {
      "order": 11,
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "Linebreak Before INTO"
      
    },
    "sqlinform.ID159LinebreakAfterInto": {
      "order": 12,
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "Linebreak After INTO"
     
    },
    "sqlinform.ID182LinebreakBeforeFrom": {
      "order": 13,
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "Linebreak Before FROM"
      
    },
    "sqlinform.ID143LinebreakAfterFrom": {
      "order": 14,
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,          
      "description": "Linebreak After FROM"
      
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the screenshot of the Setting Panel. The properties are still alphabetically ordered and the "order" property was no taken into consideration. For example, ID143LinebreakAfterFrom should be shown as last setting but it is shown on top of the list.

[image]

Any idea of what is going wrong here?

Looking to the general overview of the settings, they are shown in the correct sequence, i.e. in the sequence of the "order" property

[image]

Comment: Just for testing, what happens if you omit the numbers, like `143` or `ID143` from each of the settings?  Does the order change?

Comment: For what's it worth, I copied/pasted your settings into one of my extensions and in the Extension Host settings it ordered them as you wanted.

Comment: @Mark thx, this is very interesting info. Would you mind showing me your package.json so that I can compare them. It looks like I have an issue in my package.json file. can we send private messages in stackoverflow?

Comment: The `package.json` is here: https://github.com/ArturoDent/highlight-files.  I enabled Discussions there if you want to talk about something.